# Setting value of a Select2 without submitting form

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I start using Select2 to replace my dropdowns in my app. My question is about how to adapt what works now.

I have a page with a fullcalendar component and 3 dropdowns to choose the calendar I want to display. Once a dropdown is used, the other 2 are resetted like that (i use jQuery) :

```
$('#dropdown1').prop('selectedIndex',0)
```

The main advantage of this is that the form is only submitted by the "changed" dropdown (each dropdown has their own change event catched to reset the others).

Using select2, if i use this, the change event of the resetted dropdown is launched :

```
$('#dropdown1').select2('val','')
```

So all change events are launched.

Is there any solution to set the value of a select2 dropdown without launching the change event ?

Thank you

Comment: are you sure with `$('#dropdown1').select2('val','')` triggers the change event

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using django-select2 that uses v4.0.0.

Comment: @Reddy yes, when I change the dropdown2 and reset the dropdown1 value, the on('change') on dropdown1 is triggerred

Comment: So that might be the default behavior of the API, what you can do is have a flag check in the change event and when ever you are changing the value manually and dont want the change event to execute just escape it from a if check with the flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs for version 4 you can now call `val()` directly. From what I'm reading that won't cause the `onChange` because they say you have to call it manually.

Snippet from the docs

```
$('select').val('US'); // Change the value or make some change to the internal state
$('select').trigger('change.select2'); // Notify only Select2 of changes
```

So then I think you'd skip the `trigger` call in your case.

Comment: Problem is solved, I used your answer but I needed to trigger the change.select2.

I explain myself :
$('select').val('US'); ==> only set up a new value for initial dropdown
$('select').trigger('change.select2'); ==> triggers the change only to select2 to change the value of select2 dropdown. It DOES NOT trigger the change event to the whole page (so if you have, like me, a "onchange event" catch, it won't trigger it)

Thanks !